# How to Restart a Backgrounded Task in a Backgrounded iOS App?

Tags: maui

In a backgrounded MAUI iOS app, using BeginBackgroundTask with an expiration delegate to start a task that successfully executes, once the delegate is called and EndBackgroundTask is executed, how is a restart of the task as backgrounded accomplished?

Currently, the app remains backgrounded and does not terminate. However, if the BeginBackgroundTask method is called in the delegate after the EndBackgroundTask, the app is terminated.

Comment: You could refer to [iOS Background Execution Limits](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/685525). Could not run code periodically at a guaranteed interval.

Comment: Once time is up, its up. No cross-platform solution; read about native iOS background execution. Put corresponding c# in your iOS folder. Periodically sending a "silent push notification" from a server seems to be the only way to get iOS to reliably do background work, beyond the execution time limit. I don't have link for that. There are many discussions of only-partly-successful attempts to get iOS to reliably run periodic background tasks (without a push from a server). [Here is one](https://uynguyen.github.io/2020/09/26/Best-practice-iOS-background-processing-Background-App-Refresh-Task/).